# Installing the Neo4j in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

We were developing the social networking website so we need to use the Neo4j database with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS   but we are not able to do that due to some unknown error.

Earlier we had successfully installed the Neo4j in Ubuntu 14.04
https://www.techuz.com/blog/installing-neo4j-ubuntu-14-04-step-step-guide/

Can anybody suggest the step to install the neo4j in ubuntu 18.04.1?

Comment: Steps are the same . So what is your `unknown error` when you install Neo4j on your ubuntu 18 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm have the same problem, in the installation of Neo4J in Ubuntu Server 18.04.01 LTS:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies

Run this commands in "Terminal" and try again, work for me.

```
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
    sudo apt-get update
```

Here where i found this solution:

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/4417

Bye.